# insert category ID from wordpress admin in query

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show posts of a specific category in my home page, but I want to echo this category ID or slug from the admin theme option, so I made theme option and I can echo anything with this code

```
<?php $news1 = get_option("mytheme_news1"); echo $news1; ?>
```

The problem is i want to use above code instead of "10" (category ID) in this code.

```
<?php
$args=array(
'category__in' => ?> 10 ,
'posts_per_page' => 15
);
$videos = new WP_Query($args);
if($videos->have_posts()) : while($videos->have_posts()) : $videos->the_post(); ?>
```

Comment: I am sorry, but i don't see the problem. If $news1 get the right value, it should be enough to call 'category__in' => get_option("mytheme_news1"). Or if you want to do it clean, simply define it before and call it as $news1 like 'category__in' => $news1

Comment: Why did you close `php` tag?